# Azure Monitor - tracing in application insights

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

I have this rule set up in monitor
[image]

With this condition
[image]

It looks after traces with severity 3 or 4 on my application insights. I want to know if there is added a lot of tracing with severity >= 3 with in a timespan of 15 minutes - kinda like an abnormal rise (i guess). But now I am wondering: Am i monitoring the application insights resource itself, or is this actually looking inside application insights, and querying after trace data?

I am kind of new into the whole monitoring in Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your setting, the last one you mentioned is correct: **this is actually looking inside application insights, and querying after trace data**